# Start a firebase function project with node.js and react.js client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, firebase, express

I am developing an application with `node.js` and `express.js` hosted on firebase using `firebase functions`, and development in typescript. I would like to use `react.js` as client side framework. I set up `node + express + firebase` using:

```
firebase init hosting
firebase init functions
```

However, there is no obvious way to set up `react` front end framework using `create-react-app ...` given the current project setup. In particular, `create-react-app` seem to create its own node_module and `index.js`. I found this: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0

It is a bit ad-hoc. In particular, it is launching a dev server using `yarn`, but I am using `firebase serve ...`, and would like to keep it that way. Do these different frameworks play together at all?   #webDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use React and Firebase together, but merging the complex templates generated by starter kits for each may be more trouble than it's worth.

You will likely need to pick which generated template gives you the most value (whether it be from `firebase init hosting` or `create-react-app`) and then work on standing up items from the non-chosen ones piece by piece.

If you really want to use `firebase serve` you will be losing hot-reload and other development time benefits that `create-react-app` provides, as `firebase serve` internally uses `superstatic` ([repo](https://github.com/firebase/superstatic)) which is a dev server for hosting static files.

You can use React with such a setup by `npm install --save react react-dom` and then using React as normal, but it's very likely that you will want a toolchain between your source and the static files that `firebase serve` serves (given your use of the `typescript` tag, I'm assuming you at least need to transpile .ts to .js), and you will then need to set that up on your own if you simply want to use `firebase-serve`.

In my opinion, the dev toolchain that you get through `create-react-app` will provide more immediate value for your specific situation than wanting to stick with `firebase serve`. Is there any specific reason you feel glued to `firebase serve`?

(Not using `firebase serve` in no way causes issues running `firebase deploy --only hosting` later when you want to deploy to firebase hosting, as long as your hosting config points to the directory where `npm run build` outputs your built files.)

Comment: how does node.js fit into this picture? I'm picture something like this: https://codeburst.io/build-simple-medium-com-on-node-js-and-react-js-a278c5192f47. although the example uses mongodb